# Xcode8 Issue with "GPRCClient.framework"

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting this error in `Xcode` when running on a **real device** and I could not find a solution. Running on **simulator** works fine.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GRPCClient.framework/GRPCClient Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/87E018E3-6128-41B7-B285-417FAF97143D/vivisell.app/vivisell 
  Reason: image not found
```

[image: This is the picture]

Comment: Most probably you didn't initialized cocopods and required framework was not downloaded.